# Engine yard - outgoing TCP connections

Tags: engineyard

I'm evaluating Engine Yard. I know that some other PaaS vendors that 'sandbox' limitations on the application - e.g. don't allow them to open threads, don't allow outgoing TCP connections.

Are there such limitations on Engine Yard.
In particular, is it ok for my application to open outgoing (client) TCP connection to some legacy system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Engine Yard does not restrict outbound TCP connections, so you should have no problem connecting to legacy systems.